# which package I should added for my Windows 7 Embedded to open zip file?

Tags: windows-7, embedded

Want to open zip file in my Windows 7 Embedded. which package I should include to my Answer File? thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you require exactly, but this may help: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Comment: I am create Win7 embedded OS answer file for our embedded OS with ICE.